# patterns in a deep matrix/dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, tidyr

I am trying to find the frequency of patterns in a deep matrix/dataframe (cols: id, variable, value) with 10s of millions of rows.  This is easy to do in a wide matrix as shown below. I was wondering if there was a way to do the same (in a deep matrix) without first converting to wide format.  Thanks.

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

set.seed(100)
ncol <- 10
nrow <- 100000

#create sample matrix in wide format
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix((runif(nrow*ncol)>0.8) + 0, ncol=ncol))
cols <- colnames(df1)
df1 <- filter(df1, rowSums(df1)>0)
df1 <- cbind(id=seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1)

#compute frequency of patterns
out1 <- df1 %>%
    group_by_(.dots=cols) %>% summarise(freq=n()) %>% as.data.frame() %>% arrange(desc(freq))

#convert to deep format
df2 <- df1 %>% 
    gather(variable, value, -id) %>% filter(value>0)

#compute frequency of patterns
out2 <- df2 %>% spread(variable, value, fill=0) %>% 
    group_by_(.dots=cols) %>% summarise(freq=n()) %>% as.data.frame() %>% arrange(desc(freq))

identical(out1, out2)
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do.  Patterns of what? Please make the example data a lot smaller and show what you want as a result. Perhaps you're looking for `rowwise()`

Comment: @RichardScriven, when you reduce the problem to 10x100 you can understand the problem - counting the duplicated rows (all columns except "id").

Comment: @RichardScriven please set ncol to 3 and nrow to 50 to get a small example.

Comment: @ironv - Keep in mind that you're the one asking for help so you should be the one putting in the extra effort making it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility for the 'wide' arrangement is to paste the columns together

```
id = do.call(paste, c(df1[, -1], sep="*"))
```

and table the results

```
table(id)
```

Somehow this seems simpler than the dplyr syntax, though relying on a 'trick' instead of general operations. Other summaries are straight-forward, e.g., by column index and count

```
uid = unique(id)
data.frame(rowid=match(uid, id), count=tabulate(match(id, uid)))
```

or augmenting a unique version of the data.frame with the count information

```
cbind(df1[!duplicated(id),,drop=FALSE], count = tabulate(match(id, uid)))
```

For the (filtered) deep representation, I generated the data

```
set.seed(100)
ncol <- 10; nrow <- 100000
m1 <- matrix((runif(nrow*ncol)>0.8) + 0, ncol=ncol)
m1 <- m1[rowSums(m1) != 0,]                         # filter
m2 <- cbind(id=as.vector(row(m1)), var=as.vector(col(m1)), val=as.vector(m1))
```

then iterated through each column to calculate a unique 'key' by shifting the (unique index of the) value by enough to make the key unique

```
nid <- max(m2[,"id"])
nvar <- max(m2[,"var"])
key <- numeric(nid)
scale <- 1
for (i in seq_len(nvar)) {
    idx <- m2[, "var"] == i
    id <- m2[idx, "id"]
    val <- m2[idx, "val"]
    uval <- sort(unique(val))    # sort() not strictly necessary
    key[id] <- key[id] + scale * (match(val, uval) - 1L)
                                 # match() allows for non-integer 'val'
    scale <- scale * length(uval)
}
```

The keys can be summarized into a count table

```
ukey <- unique(key)
out2m <- data.frame(ukey=ukey,
                    rowid=seq_len(nid)[match(ukey, key)],
                    count=tabulate(match(key, ukey)))
```

and displayed in various ways

```
o <- order(out2m$count, decreasing=TRUE)
head(out2m[o,])
m1[out2m$rowid[head(o)],]
```

This is faster and more memory-efficient that dplyr, but again a special purpose algorithm. It also requires that the scale be less than the maximum number of unique double-precision numbers, something like 2^53.

It's a little hard to know where to start and end a benchmark, but since the data could as easily be a data frame or matrix, and since we're apparently interested in counts maybe the following are reasonable

```
fdf2 <- function(df2) {
    group_by(df2, id) %>% arrange(id, variable) %>%
        summarise(pattern = toString(value)) %>%
            count(pattern)
}

fm2 <- function(m2) {
    nid <- max(m2[,"id"])
    nvar <- max(m2[,"var"])
    key <- numeric(nid)
    scale <- 1
    for (i in seq_len(nvar)) {
        idx <- m2[, "var"] == i
        id <- m2[idx, "id"]
        val <- m2[idx, "val"]
        uval <- sort(unique(val))
        key[id] <- key[id] + scale * (match(val, uval) - 1L)
        scale <- scale * length(uval)
    }

    ukey <- unique(key)
    data.frame(ukey=ukey, rowid=seq_len(nid)[match(ukey, key)],
               count=tabulate(match(key, ukey)))
}
```

No need for [microbenchmark](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/) or similar,

```
> system.time(fdf2(df2))
   user  system elapsed 
  4.640   0.000   4.639 
> system.time(fm2(m2))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.587   0.000   0.587
```

It could be that the simulated data are not realistic, or that the algorithms scale differently and that one or the other is more competitive with the real data; the question as originally posed is not phrased clearly enough to perform more relevant tests.

Memory use is harder to gauge in R; I guessed that fm2 makes needs no more than the memory to hold a `nvar * 3` elements, e.g., if all doubles

```
> print(object.size(double(nid)) * 3, units="auto")
2 Mb
```

I guess dplyr is clever, so harder to reason about, but some of the intermediate objects are large, e.g.,

```
> print(object.size(group_by(df2, id)), units="auto")
22.5 Mb
```

I'm actually not really sure how to easily characterize memory use rigorously, especially since dplyr calls in to C code and may well use non-R memory.

Comment: Is the `df1` you are using here, the `df1` from the question (e.g. in wide format)?

Comment: @beginneR yep, my misunderstanding I'll remove the response

Comment: Did you benchmark the approaches or how do you know it's faster and more memory efficient? Would be nice to see those benchmarks.

Comment: @beginneR it was faster 'by eye', but I've added some attempts at a more rigorous analysis.

Comment: Thanks for adding the comparison! I guess the problem is (as you already said in your answer) that the question and expected result is not 100% clearly defined which is why our approaches produce differnt things, yours creates a unique "key" for each pattern while mine keeps the original patterns in the output. Nice work (+1)

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment)

<strike>I doubt that it's possible (can't say for sure, though).</strike>

Two challenges:

- in the long format, each unique "pattern" is distributed over at least `ncol` rows. How would you use "summarise" and break this down to a single row (which could only hold a single value which means it's an incomplete pattern)?
- Second problem I see with your sample code: when you create df2 and
  use `filter(value > 0)` you effectively destroy most of the existing
  patterns because the vast majority of patterns (in wide format)
  include 0s in some rows. The only *complete* pattern that you could still
  observe then could consist of only 1s, right?

More precisely: It might be possible, but I believe it would require a greater workaround than conversion from long to wide.

---

I just changed my mind, but I'm not sure whether this really so much different than conversion from long to wide format:

```
out2 <- group_by(df2, id) %>% arrange(id, variable) %>%
          summarise(pattern = toString(value)) %>%
           count(pattern)
```

Result:

```
> out2 %>% arrange(desc(n))
Source: local data frame [896 x 2]

                        pattern    n
1  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 2794
2  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 2754
3  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 2742
4  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 2716
5  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 2716
6  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 2710
7  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 2685
8  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 2633
9  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 2630
10 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 2618
..                          ...  ...
```

To compare to the other data and generate `df2`, I use:

```
set.seed(100)
ncol <- 10
nrow <- 100000

#create sample matrix in wide format
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix((runif(nrow*ncol)>0.8) + 0, ncol=ncol))
cols <- colnames(df1)
df1 <- filter(df1, rowSums(df1)>0)
df1 <- cbind(id=seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1)

#compute frequency of patterns
out1 <- df1 %>%
    group_by_(.dots=cols) %>% summarise(freq=n()) %>% as.data.frame() %>% arrange(desc(freq))

#convert to deep format
df2 <- df1 %>%                      # this is the input for my code
    gather(variable, value, -id)    # note that I don't use `filter(value>0)` here!
```

Compare with out1:

```
> head(out1[order(-out1$freq),])
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 freq
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0 2794
2  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0 2754
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1 2742
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0 2716
5  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0 2716
6  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0 2710
```

Obviously, I can't use `identical(out1, out2)` here because `out2` only has 2 columns .. but I can use it on the frequency counts:

```
identical(out1$freq, out2$n)
#[1] TRUE
```

.. and if you wanted to convert out2 to something identical to out1, you could use `separate` from tidyr:

```
separate(out2, col = pattern, into = paste0("V", seq_len(ncol)), sep = ",")
```

Comment: the following variant of your code allows us to not have to fill in the zeroes.  My matrix is VERY sparse and I would prefer not to have to add back the zeroes.    `df2$val <- paste0(df2$variable,df2$value);
    out3 <- group_by(df2, id) %>% arrange(id, variable) %>%
              summarise(pattern = toString(val)) %>%
               count(pattern) %>% as.data.frame() %>% arrange(desc(n))`  I wonder if there is a way to avoid the paste0 in a separate step.  Unfortunately though, this approach is much slower than that in the original post.

Comment: Here's another variant  `out3 <- df2 %>% arrange(id, variable) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(varval=paste0(variable,value)) %>%
              summarise(pattern=toString(varval)) %>% count(pattern) %>% as.data.frame() %>% arrange(desc(n))`  It is still much slower than the approach in the OP.  Would be interesting to look at memory requirement.